# Why Jasmine spy function in Angular is not being triggered by callback?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, callback, jasmine

I want to test `this.communication.subscribe()` call which is having a callback in argument:

```
constructor (private communication: CommunicationProvider)

ngOnInit() {
    this.communication.subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigate(["/success"]);
    });
  }
```

I have used [callFake](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callFake%3C/code%3E) to mock the implementation to call callback()

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    communicationSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj("CommunicationProvider", ["subscribe"]);
    routerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<Router>("Router", ["navigate"]);

    communicationSpy.subscribe.and.callFake((callback: any) => {
        callback();
    });
}));

it("should route on callback", (done: DoneFn) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(["/success"]);
        done();
    }, 3000);
});
```

As per code coverage results, `this.router.navigate(["/success"]);` is being covered by `callback()`.
But `"should route on callback"` test is failing as `routerSpy.navigate` is never being called.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because you never trigger the subscription.

I don't know what your service is, but we'll take advantage of the fact that you don't use restriction operators such as `take` or `takeUntil`.

Start by mocking your observable as a hot stream with a `Subject` :

```
component['communication'] = new Subject() as any;
```

Now, you should have a new instance of your component in every test thanks to the fixture `createComponentInstance` called in the before each. This means you already have called `ngOnInit` and created the subscription.

Since the stream is hot, you can subscribe to it in your test :

```
it('should navigate', done => {
  component['communication'].subscribe(() => {
    expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(["/success"]);
    done();
  });

  (component['communication'] as Subject).next(true);
});
```

With the `next` call, you trigger the subscriptions, launching the router and expecting it to have been called.

(P.S : I have used array syntax and `Subject` to picture the issue, feel free to use whatever you want to trigger a subscription and to mock your dependencies)